# Open file in app by dragging it onto taskbar icon

Tags: windows-10, taskbar

One of the features I depend on in macOS is opening a file in a specific app by dragging it onto the app icon in the Dock.

Is there a way to do this in Windows 10? I tried dragging a file onto the icon in the Taskbar, yet the default action is pinning the file.

Answer (score 5):

Hold the Shift key while dragging the file, and drop into a taskbar app. The file will be opened with the app in taskbar.

Comment: without the shift key, one can also hover over the application in the taskbar and it will maximize/restore and then the file can be dropped. Exactly where to drop it can vary but dropping it on the application's  top bar is often where it will open (as opposed to inserted into an existing document)

Comment: This only works if the app on the taskbar supports drag and drop of files.

Comment: @DavidPostill the OP's wanted file seems to be allowed drag and drop?

Comment: @Yorik thank you but yours will require to open the app in taskbar.

Comment: @WasifHasan Yes, the first application may support dragging a file but the second application has to support drop **when it is minimised to the taskabar**

Comment: There are many apps, vlc for example, that will not allow a drop onto the minimised program, but if you wait till it restores by hovering you can then release the mouse and it will drop. In this case drop is only allowed in the video play area (which is not the whole application) and this drop area is not part of what is displayed when vlc is minimised.

Comment: So the answer is it depends.

Comment: Thank you for your suggestions!

Comment: This works! But is there a way to make this the default behavior (i.e., without holding Shift)?